# How do I prove the expectation value formula for the momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum, wavefunction

I know that according to textbooks $⟨p⟩ = −iℏ∫ψ^{*}(x)\frac{dψ(x)}{dx}dx$, but why? Knowing that $I = ∫|x⟩⟨x|dx$

I get $⟨p⟩ = ⟨ψ|p|ψ⟩ = ∫⟨ψ|p|x⟩⟨x|ψ⟩dx = ∫(−iℏ\frac{dψ(x)}{dx})^{*}ψ(x)dx$,

but also $⟨p⟩ = ⟨ψ|p|ψ⟩ = ∫⟨ψ|x⟩⟨x|p|ψ⟩dx = ∫ψ(x)^{*}(−iℏ\frac{dψ(x)}{dx})dx$.

Now I would expect that $∫(−iℏ\frac{dψ(x)}{dx})^{*}ψ(x)dx = ∫ψ(x)^{*}(−iℏ\frac{dψ(x)}{dx})dx$, but this is not the case.. why?

Comment: Why do you say that is not the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you have two definitions of the expectation value of momentum and want to show that they are equivalent. It's easy to do this using integration by parts, given the properties of the wavefunction.

For example, if you start with your "first" definition,

$$\langle p \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty i \hbar \frac{\text{d}\psi^*}{\text{d} x} \psi(x).$$

One can now "shift" the derivative from the first term to the second using integration by parts, since

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty i \hbar \frac{\text{d}\psi^*}{\text{d} x} \psi(x) = \psi(x) \psi^*(x)\Big|_{-\infty}^\infty - \int_{-\infty}^\infty i \hbar\, \psi^*(x)\frac{\text{d}\psi}{\text{d} x}. $$

Realising that for any "physical" wavefunction $|\psi(x)|^2 \to 0$ as $x\to \pm \infty$, the first term is trivially zero, and so

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty i \hbar \frac{\text{d}\psi^*}{\text{d} x} \psi(x) = - \int_{-\infty}^\infty i \hbar\, \psi^*(x)\frac{\text{d}\psi}{\text{d} x}. $$

Does this answer your question?

Comment: thanks, that clears it up!!

Comment: This may be pedantic, but it’s not Entirely clear to me why the limit of $\Psi \frac{d\Psi}{dx} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.  I can come up with $\Psi$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Psi^* \Psi dx = 1$.

Comment: but for which this is not technically true in the sense that it is Not true that $\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists x_0 $ such that $ x > x_0 \implies \lvert \Psi(x) - 0 \rvert < \epsilon $ .

Comment: Consider, for example, a sequence $\{ a_i \}$ whose sum converges to 1.  Then construct a $\Psi(x)$ which is 0 everywhere, except for spikes, centred at integers $i$, of area $a_i$.  

Furthermore, if the spikes are made narrower as their area decreases, but not shorter, then $\frac{d\Psi}{dx}$ doesn’t approach 0 either, but actually a monotonically Increasing series can be found.